# Importing domains to ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, domains

Is there a way to import a geodatabase into a sde on the server and keep the sde domains, while adding the new geodatabse domains?

Comment: Domain to Table from file gdb, then Table to Domain in enterprise gdb

Comment: @Midavalo I think you should write an answer from your comment.  Your hesitation may be whether the asker is using ArcGIS 10.0, and whether those tools were available then, but the asker has not written in their question body whether they are using 10.0 or 10.x so I think answering w.r.t. the lastest dot release of 10.x is fine.